# I've got some issues while trying to send messages to multiple iPhones

Tags: c#, ios, azure, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to send `PushNotification` to multiple devices.

1.I added the phone `Identifier` to `Devices` in apple web `developer` `account`.

2.I downloaded the `Provisioning Profile` in `Visual Studio`(I'm developing it on windows connected to mac mini)

3.I started the project(simple push notification, receiving only message if robots get an error and sends it to the client), It was downloaded successful on the iPhone.

4.I tested it and we both received message(first I was texting only with my phone), after a while I tried to send a message again, but the 2nd phone only received it. I got no idea where is the problem with that. I have read that `Notification Hub` supports 10 test devices.

Any suggestion?

Thank you for the invested time to read my question!

Comment: Hi Zdravko,did you see any APNS Errors on your Dashboard? are both iOS devices iOS 10 (or later version)?

Comment: No errors at all, both devices are later thah 10 version.

Answer (score 0):

When sending notification ensure that you set the expiration. Default value is zero. Hence, APNs treats the notification as if it expires immediately and does not store the notification or attempt to redeliver it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html

**`apns-expiration`**

If this value is nonzero, APNs stores the notification and tries to deliver it at least once, repeating the attempt as needed if it is unable to deliver the notification the first time. If the value is 0, APNs treats the notification as if it expires immediately and does not store the notification or attempt to redeliver it.

```
var notification = new TemplateNotification(new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
 {"APNS_Expiry", DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10).ToString("o") }, //Timestamp
                        {"body", NotificationText},
                        {"payload", NotificationText},
                        {"deeplinking", payload},
                    }); 
            var Responsehub = hub.SendNotificationAsync(notification);
```

Also for trouble shooting , you can refer below doc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer

Hope it helps.